Mavros command line utilities - how to install them?
Mavros documentation says something about command line utilities (section 5: http://wiki.ros.org/mavros), but I don't see my bash completes these commands after mavros and mavros-extras installation. Do you know how to install them?
ros2 run mavros mavcmd or ros2 run mavros mavparam give error:

No executable found

